# width of paragraph in Elm

Tags: html, elm

Trying to make paragraph a certain width but the paragraph runs over.  Why does Elm ignore me?

That width **must** be an integer, so I gave it the width in pixels.

```
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)


info : String
info = "Ports must be careful about what values are allowed through. Elm is statically typed, so each port is fitted with some border protection code that ensures that type errors are kept out. Ports also do some conversions so that you get nice colloquial data structures in both Elm and JS."

main = p [ Html.Attributes.width 500] [ text info ]
```

Elm-Reactor just compiles it to a `<p> ... </p>` with no attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use "style" from Html.Attributes

```
style [ ("width", "100px") ]
```

According to the docs the "Html.Attributes.width" function is not for paragraphs.

> width : Int -> Attribute msg
>
> Declare the width of a canvas, embed, iframe, img, input, object, or video.

http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/1.0.0/Html-Attributes#width

Comment: OK... do you know why `<p>` is treated differently?

Comment: This is standard Html: in Html, `<p>` elements do not have a `width = ` attribute. They can have a `style = ` attribute. And inside the style, you can set the width (and any other css/ style attribute).

Answer (score 4):

You are confusing `width` HTML Attribute with CSS property with the same name.

> **width**
>
> For the elements listed here, this establishes the element's width.
>
> **Note:** For all other instances, such as , this is a legacy attribute, in which case the CSS width property should be used instead
>
> `<canvas>, <embed>, <iframe>, <img>, <input>, <object>, <video>`

CSS property

```
p [ style [ ("width", "100px") ] ] [ text "Hello World!" ]
-- <p style="width: 100px">Hello World</p>
```

HTML Attribute

```
iframe [ width 100 ] []
-- <iframe width="100px"></iframe>
```